# How to add different legends to a multiple plot?

Tags: r, plot, model, legend, population

Okay so I have used the par function to combine multiple plots. 
I added legends and it's all fun and games until some plots need different legends than others and I can't figure out the programming gymnastics required to make it work.

I've included the part where I have my legends under the name "This is the part where I need help", as you see, there are four of them, for N1, N2, K1 and K2, with abline and text functions for each.

I tried to make lists of concatenations and such but it didn't work as well as with my alphas, and I have spent far too long researching how to make it work.

```
##II - Species Competition : testing different parameter combinations with a loop

#Clearing workspace
rm(list=ls())
graphics.off()

#Parameters set on types (lambda 1, lambda 2, alphas...)

years <- 50
Lambda1set<-c(5,5,3,3.2)
Lambda2set<-c(4,4,5,2.5)
Alphaset<-list(matrix(c(0.01, 0.007, 0.0045, 0.01),ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE),
               matrix(c(0.01, 0.004, 0.009, 0.01),ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE),
               matrix(c(0.01, 0.0065, 0.003, 0.01),ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE),
               matrix(c(0.005, 0.005, 0.0045, 0.003),ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))

#Creating vectors

TimeVec<-seq(1,years+1)
N1<-matrix(0,4,years+1)
N2<-matrix(0,4,years+1)

#INITIALIZATION
N0 <- 40
##N1[1] <-N0
##N2[1] <-N0
for(i in 1:4){
  N1[i,1] <-N0
  N2[i,1] <-N0
}

for (t in 1:years){
  for(i in 1:4){ 
    alphs <- Alphaset[[i]]

    N1[i,t+1]<-(Lambda1set[i]*N1[i,t])/(1+alphs[1,1]*N1[i,t]+alphs[1,2]*N2[i,t])
    N2[i,t+1]<-(Lambda2set[i]*N2[i,t])/(1+alphs[2,1]*N1[i,t]+alphs[2,2]*N2[i,t])
  }
}

## Plotting
titles<-c("Both species coexist","Species 1 wins","Species 2 wins",
          "Whoever comes first")
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

for(i in 1:4){

  plot(TimeVec,N1[i,],type="l",main = titles[i], xlab='Time (years)',
       ylab='Population Density',col='blue',lwd = 2,ylim = c(-100,500))
  lines(TimeVec,N2[i,],type="l",col='green', lwd = 2)
  legend("topright", legend = c("Species 1", "Species 2"),lty = 1, 
         col = c("blue", "green"),lwd = 2, bty = "n")

  #Adding equilibria

  R1<-(Lambda1set-1)
  R2<-(Lambda2set-1)
  alphs <- Alphaset[[i]]

  ### This is the part where I need help
  N1eq <- (R1[i]*alphs[2,2]-R2[i]*alphs[1,2])/
    (alphs[1,1]*alphs[2,2]-alphs[2,1]*alphs[1,2])
  abline(h = N1eq, lty = 3)
  text(0, N1eq, "n1*", adj = c(0, 0))

  N2eq <- (R2[i]*alphs[1,1]-R1[i]*alphs[2,1])/
    (alphs[1,1]*alphs[2,2]-alphs[2,1]*alphs[1,2])
  abline(h = N2eq, lty = 3)
  text(0, N2eq, "n2*", adj = c(0, 0))

  K1 <- R1[i]/alphs[1,1]
  K2 <- R2[i]/alphs[2,2]

  abline(h = K1, lty = 3)
  text(0, K1, "K1", adj = c(0, 0))
  abline(h = K2, lty = 3)
  text(0, K2, "K2", adj = c(0, 0))

  #Invasion scores
  Inv1<-((R1[i])/(R2[i]))*(alphs[2,2]/alphs[1,2])
  Inv2<-((R2[i])/(R1[i]))*(alphs[1,1]/alphs[2,1])
  print(c(Inv1,Inv2))

  #abline(h = 1/alphs[1, 1], lty = 3)
  #text(0, 1/alphs[1, 1], "K", adj = c(0, 0))

}
```

[image: Plot Output]

What I wish I would have is N1 and N2 on the first plot, K1 on the second and fourth and K2 on the third. Thank you all for your help !

Sam

Comment: First thank you for a reproducible example! But can you clarify your needs in last sentence? Do you need those N* and K* to replace Species 1 and 2 in legends?

Comment: Youre welcome ! No, I don't need them to replace anything, the rest of the legends are fine because they apply to each plots, it's just those ones that are different from one plot to the next. Right now they apply to every plots, what I want is : 
-Plot 1 -> N1eq and N2eq lines (abline) with texted names (text) "n1*" and "n2*" above them, at x=0 and h=N1eq and N2eq lines, respectively.; Plot 2 -> K1 abline and text; Plot 3 -> K2 abline and text; Plot 4 -> K1 abline and text.

Comment: Can you create a visual for your desired result possibly using some graphics software? You can then link the image or screenshot to your post. Showing is always better than telling.

Comment: Sure I can, here, I did this quickly on Paint and Photoshop. I'm sorry, yesterday was a day off ! https://puu.sh/DKXrM/d23ed641b6.png

Comment: Hello ? I still need an answer sorry

Comment: Hmmm...I answered below yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Consider conditionally plotting the needed `ablines` according to the *i* loop iterator. See below for adjustment in your help section

```
  ### This is the part where I need help
  if(i == 1) {
    N1eq <- (R1[i]*alphs[2,2]-R2[i]*alphs[1,2])/
      (alphs[1,1]*alphs[2,2]-alphs[2,1]*alphs[1,2])
    abline(h = N1eq, lty = 3)
    text(0, N1eq, "n1*", adj = c(0, 0))

    N2eq <- (R2[i]*alphs[1,1]-R1[i]*alphs[2,1])/
      (alphs[1,1]*alphs[2,2]-alphs[2,1]*alphs[1,2])
    abline(h = N2eq, lty = 3)
    text(0, N2eq, "n2*", adj = c(0, 0))
  }

  if (i %in% c(2,4)) {
    K1 <- R1[i]/alphs[1,1]
    abline(h = K1, lty = 3)
    text(0, K1, "K1", adj = c(0, 0))
  }

  if (i == 3) {
    K2 <- R2[i]/alphs[2,2]
    abline(h = K2, lty = 3)
    text(0, K2, "K2", adj = c(0, 0))
  }
```

[image: Plot Output]